# Object undefined (Javascript) in localhost but not in production

Tags: javascript, asp.net, debugging, undefined

We have two Javascript files being loaded on an ASP.NET page. One is CommonUI.js and another is Entity.Js

The page calls a function in Entity.Js that calls a function in CommonUI.Js. However, in my local environment I am getting the error "CommonUI" is undefined.

In their production environment this is fine.

I've checked that CommonUI.js is loaded and it is. Debugging this fires the function in Entity.Js but fails because the function being called on CommonUI (CommonUI.WindowResize() ) points to an object that's undefined.

So my question is ... why is CommonUI not defined in only my localhost?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: I've seen this question before.....

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue could be related to the paths being used for your JS files.

You could add a reference to both JS files in the header of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/Entity.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/CommonUI.js") %>'></script>
```

If you are using a master page structure you may need to wrap the references within an ASP Placeholder server control.

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/Entity.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/CommonUI.js") %>'></script>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: I verified that the paths are relative and they do resolve to the files themselves.
However, mine loads CommonUI first and then Entity in that order.

Comment: can you post your markup ? It's very hard to help without seeing some markup.